# Can't verify webhook Rails (invalid signature)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to integrate paddle.com subscriptions into my Rails app

Here is the code

```
require 'base64'
require 'php_serialize'
require 'openssl'
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def check
    public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAr7/mDtqUWyh2bb2QSkUE
PAPP7pwc6RhQrf9ikKVmssNTn0bDUcOi5dDhWON2u1xpAl6OMAX9lCPY7saHqzJR
MQrj0D3EmKDcXTBFnQWEOx4pToxhGsjpahGnq0kOtlig+1zFyYz78Wn3a58dxTIi
m1K6MOHj7R8TP2k6haLE8ZECAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
      data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    else
      data = params.as_json
    end

    signature = Base64.decode64(data['p_signature'])
    data.delete('p_signature')
    data.each {|key, value|data[key] = String(value)}
    data_sorted = data.sort_by{|key, value| key}

    data_serialized = PHP.serialize(data_sorted, true)

    digest    = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new
    pub_key   = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(public_key).public_key
    verified  = pub_key.verify(digest, signature, data_serialized)

    if verified
      puts 'Yay ok'
      head :ok
    else
      puts 'The signature is invalid!'
    end

  end
  end
```

I test it with Paddle webhook simulator, but the error I got is an invalid signature.  "The signature is invalid", which means can't be verified

```
Processing by SubscriptionsController#check as */*
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "p_signature"=>"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"}
The signature is invalid!
No template found for SubscriptionsController#check, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

How can I verify it?

Paddle docs [here](https://developer.paddle.com/webhook-reference/verifying-webhooks)

Comment: Don't inline this  in a controller. Create a separate class/module that you can call from your tests (you are writing tests aren't you?) by passing in a hash and whatever else it needs. The way you are parsing the response body is also completely redundant and broken - Rails will automatically parse the body and provide it in the params hash. `#as_json` is ActiveModel method. `#to_json` is how you convert other objects to json.

Comment: @max I'm new to rails, how can I call it from the model? thank you

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @ccoeder yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solve it

Subscription.rb

```
    require 'base64'
    require 'php_serialize'
    require 'openssl'
    class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      attr_accessor :reference
      belongs_to :plan
    
    
      def self.verified(data)
    
        public_key = %q(-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
   xxxxxxxxxx
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----)
    
        begin
          # 'data' represents all of the POST fields sent with the request.
          # Get the p_signature parameter & base64 decode it.
          signature = Base64.decode64(data['p_signature'])
    
          # Remove the p_signature parameter
          data.delete('p_signature')
          data.delete('action')
          data.delete('controller')
          # Ensure all the data fields are strings
          data.each {|key, value|data[key] = String(value)}
    
          # Sort the data
          data_sorted = data.sort_by{|key, value| key}
    
          # and serialize the fields
          # serialization library is available here: https://github.com/jqr/php-serialize
          data_serialized = PHP.serialize(data_sorted, true)
    
          # verify the data
          digest    = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new
          pub_key   = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(public_key).public_key
          verified  = pub_key.verify(digest, signature, data_serialized)
          verified
        rescue
          verified = false
        end
    
      end
  
      end
```

Then in your controller

```
def activate
         verification = Subscription.verified(check_params.as_json)
            alert = params[:alert_name]
        
            if verification and alert == 'subscription_created'
           ####then user create plan, etc..
           end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue. I was trying to derive `data` from `params`. However, the problem is **`params` includes extra stuff like `action` and `controller`**. The point of verifying is to make sure what you receive is exactly what Paddle sent; any extra stuff will cause verification to fail.

The solution is to get data directly from the request:

```rb
data = request.request_parameters
```